# Calling Right side drawer in another activity in android?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-view, navigation-drawer

In my android application my main activity has navigation drawer and other image views. I am trying to include right side drawer in this main activity.So I have created a separate activity which has right side drawer.
Can I call this separate activity to my main activity and make it viewable as right side drawer.

Comment: You want right drawer and left drawer in the same activity?

Comment: yes. I want clarification how we can call  activity-1 to activity-2 and make the  activity features made visible in activity-2.

Comment: why aren't you trying to implement both right and left drawer in activity-2 ? I think if you bring activity-1 to activity-2, activity-2 will lose focus and left drawer in activity-2 won't work..